# How to store large graphs, beyond adjacency lists/matrices?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, optimization, memory-management

If space is of primary concern, how could we improve on adjacency matrices and adjacency lists for representing a graph of nodes and undirected edges in memory?

Throughout academia we learn adjacency matrices and lists but in the real world we encounter graphs of sizes that exceed the capabilities of these representations.

Are there known techniques to achieve significantly smaller memory usage while maintaining the representation of the graph?

Comment: A graph is the same thing as a matrix. There is ample literature about storing sparse matrices.

Comment: Please elaborate on `graphs of sizes that exceed the capabilities of [lists]`.